# loading order JavaScript files in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am using a Rails 4 application. I installed some JavaScript plugin files in "vendor/assets/javascripts", and some in "app/assets/javascripts" where I have some files that are invoking methods from the vendor files.

No methods from these are recognized and it seems that "app/assets/javascripts" files are loaded before "vendor/assets/javascripts" files. How can I deal with that?

For information my "application.js" calls:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require rails.validations
//= require_tree .
```

and I am using `gem 'jquery-rails'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any files in your vendor tree that you need must be required explicitly in your "application.js".  It will pull in all the JavaScript in your "app/assets/" tree using the "require_tree".

You probably need to update your file to look something more like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require turbolinks
//= require rails.validations
//= require that_file_from_vendor_assets
//= require that_other_file_from_vendor_assets
//= require_tree .
```

where `that_file_from_vendor_assets` is the vendor JavaScript that you need to be loaded up before it gets to your "app/assets/javascript" files.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
//=require_tree .
```

like this:

```
//= require_self
```

Then files  will be imported in the order of you put them to your `application.js` file.

And don't forget `<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>` in your layout file.

Comment: it still doesn't work. Which file will be loaded first : those of `vendor/assets/javascripts` or of the `app/assets/javascripts` ?