# Does Rails load JS first or last?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I know I can load javascript first or later depending on where I put on my HTML. This is speaking in the case where only HTML and javascript is used. Placing javascript on the bottom of the code results in it running after the HTML is loaded and vice versa.

How does it work in Rails? Does the asset pipeline load javascript first or later?

Comment: This link may help you [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939818/loading-order-javascript-files-in-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, it's identical to what you describe. There's nothing special about how the asset pipeline works in the browser, it runs it where ever you put the `<script>` tag, just like a regular JavaScript/HTML page.